# From which matlab version, the logninv included to the statistics toolbox

Tags: matlab, probability

Concerning R2014, R2015, R2016 matlab versions, do I have to purchase statistcs toolbox to use logninv function?
( Concerning R2017a, yes )

Comment: [Introduced before R2006a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/logninv.html?s_tid=doc_ta#f1129833_seealso)

Comment: You can check here for every version: http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html, [as of 2010b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2010b/toolbox/stats/icdf.html?s_tid=srchtitle) (and probably all later versions) it is part of the toolbox

Comment: *You can check the archive for any version if you have an associated license

Comment: This function is fairly trivial to re-implement yourself as it just the inverse of the [the lognormal CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) and Matlab had an `erfcinv` function that is not part of the Statistics toolbox.